# How do I consume this xml web service in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, visual-studio

My teacher wants me to consume a web service in an effort to update a database from a central source. We never even touched on web services in class. I have no idea what's important and what's not, so here's the web service:

```
http://mis.upb.pitt.edu/dixon/WebService.asmx
```

And I'm trying

```
try
        {
            WEBSERVICE.WebService ws = new WEBSERVICE.WebService();
            XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            using (WEBSERVICE resp = ws.GetHashCode() as WEBSERVICE)
            {
                XmlDoc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
            }
            return XmlDoc;
            //XmlDoc.Load(ws);

            // Get Elements
            XmlNodeList User = XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("USER");
            XmlNodeList Password = XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("PASSWORD");
            XmlNodeList Salt = XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("SALT");
        }
        catch (Exception expe)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(expe.Message);
        }
```

Am I even close to anything resembling working code here?

Comment: No. I'm sorry to say, but this is *way* off. What is this: `WEBSERVICE resp = ws.GetHashCode() as WEBSERVICE` even supposed to be? Did you copy and paste random garbage from the internet? Your webservice instance should have method you can call. You don't need manual XML handling.

Comment: you can add a service reference within visual studio

Comment: @nvoigt Pretty much. I'm just guessing on how things fit together, or what's supposed to happen. So far I've just been googling code and shrugging and adding it if it looks like it might do what I need it to do... not that I'm sure exactly what I need it to do. Load the xml the web service gives me into the xml document I create, then parse that into my database, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Add a **service reference** to your project.[image: add service reference]

2) See *generated classes* with object browser. [image: object browser]

3) Use generated service client

```
var webServiceSoapClient = new  Q26998366_ConsumeAsmx.Dixon.WebServiceSoapClient ("WebServiceSoap");
foreach (Dixon.User user in  webServiceSoapClient.Data()) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Name: {0}\nPass: {1}\nSalt: {2}\n"
        , user.username, user.password, user.salt)); 
}
```

4) Output: [image: output]

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond, but it took me a while to figure out what you were telling me. Which is my own fault. But I figured it out and I'm getting output! I have the data! Now it's just manipulation!